# Understanding authentication in C# web forms app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I have a web app written in C# web forms and inside the web.config there is this line of code:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

It is my understanding that this means users of the application must use Windows user accounts. But this is for a web application. How does this tie in to web applications where new users can be created inside the application itself, not through Windows AD?

Secondly, despite this configuration in the web.config, the application rolls it's own authentication - there is a login form and accompanying code to log them in, log the request, create a session, and redirect them to a specific page.

So is it safe to say that this configuration is doing nothing?

And somewhat related, I am converting this application from web forms to MVC, and in the web forms project I create a session variable, but I cannot seem to access it from the MVC project. Is there a way to do so? Here is how I set it in web forms project

```
userSession = new Models.UserSession()
{
    Prop1 = value,
    Prop2 = "etc",
};
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"] = userSession;
```

And here is how I attempt to read it from the MVC project

```
var userSession = (Models.UserSession)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"];
//userSession is null.
```

Comment: one is authentication, second is authorization. it doesn't do nothing - it restricts access to only in-domain users

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication needs to be set up on the web server itself, and is disabled in newer versions by default. See this link for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/

As for the session variable, you mean that you are sharing sessions between two different applications? In that case you have to consider a shared storage solution, such as inside SQL server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/configure-sql-store-session-state

Comment: Technically they are 2 different projects, but both currently use the same user session (which is currently a cookie). In terms of hosted, the MVC project is a sub-app defined in Azure app service, so they are part of the same application, albeit web forms+MVC